# How to set up different levels of access in PHP based on an SQL table of Usernames?

Tags: php, privileges, erp

Currently I am working on an `ERP`. Being an intern, I could not find out the qptimized way to set up different level of access in which the username is fetched from the form field, matched with the existing data in database and accordingly grant the predefined privileges to the users.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to do two things.

Create a file that stores access-rights (where you define different levels, a is lowest, b,c,d, ect). Not a plain .txt file rather a file in the language you use to define constants ;)

if you use bitwise operations you could easily detect which rights the user has according to the DB you just have to put in those values.
How you design the values is up to you but i'd say use simple characters or numbers and just add em.

Example:

A is simple User
B is user with read/write access
C is user with read/write + delete access

you could build up the different access levels like that, and they would be quite simple to manage / understand.

I am using this kind of system on a game-server which fetches it's access level data (certain commands in server and on website) and these values tell the code which rights the have (They are used by 2 different languages in my case :P)

Answer (score 0):

Start here and work your way through it : [Custom ACLs](http://www.developer.com/lang/php/creating-a-custom-acl-in-php.html)